# Hide text depending on outcome of label address

Tags: ios, label, cllocationmanager

In my application the user will get his address displayed on a label when he presses a button. Depending on the position of the user, the outcome sometimes equals to "(null)". This happens often for the number of the address.
 Example: `*Infinite Loop (null), 95014 Cupertino, CA, United States*`. How do I hide (null) if it appears?

```
NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            _addressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                 placemark.thoroughfare, placemark.subThoroughfare,
                                 placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea,
                                 placemark.country];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }`

Thank you in advance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                 placemark.thoroughfare, placemark.subThoroughfare,
                                 placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea,
                                 placemark.country];

_addressLabel.text = [addressString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)"
                                     withString:@""];
```